# Get a value from a textbox in php, call another php file and pass this text box value as a variable to it

Tags: php, html, mysql, textbox

I have two php pages. They both return some MySQL tables.

I use page1.php to return the a table called "student" from the database. I am now trying to implement a search function that would help people search through the student table for a particular name.

I have created a textbox for the search ( This is in page1.php)

```
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="search">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
```

What I am trying to do is :
When the user clicks on the button "search", it calls page2.php and passes the value from the textbox to a variable called "sname" in page2.php

In page2.php

I have :

```
$sname = "matt"; /*<-- Need dynamic */
$result = mysql_query("Select * from student where phone like '%$sname%'");
```

Now I am manually feeding the value of `$sname`. How can I get the value from the textbox in page1.php to this variable?

Comment: first you need to use the html tag `name` inside the `<input>``</input>` and pass the variable using POST or GET

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: @jcho360: Is that on page2.php? 
I am new to php. Can you elaborate a bit on your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the code in **page1.php** like:

```
<form action='page2.php' method='post'>
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='search' VALUE ="search">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

now in page 2 you can use $_POST['search'], like:

```
$sname = $_POST['seach'];
```

Comment: After the button is clicked, it still stays in the same page. It does not redirect me to page2.php This is where it gets me to: localhost//page1.php?text=matt&Submit1=Search

Comment: Do you have any kind of javascript on your page?

Comment: Yes I do. But your code works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

page1.php

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE = "text" name="sname" VALUE ="search">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

on page2.php

```
$sname= $_POST['sname']
```

Comment: After the button is clicked, it still stays in the same page. It does not redirect me to page2.php
This is where it gets me to:
http://localhost//page1.php?text=matt&Submit1=Search

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your inputs are in a form

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="search" name="search">
    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

Then you can access it via

```
$sname = $_POST['search'];
```

Note that I have added a `name` attribute to your text input, this is required for the value to be in the $_POST array

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML misses the element FORM

```
<form action="page2.php" method="GET">
    <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="search" name="text">
    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
    <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="search" name="text">
    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

The first method returns the url `page2.php?text=test`. And you can access the variable with the global $_GET value

The second method returns the url `page2.php`, but holds the data in the global POST variable, $_POST.

The first method is mainly done with search things, and the second one with "private" forms. You should use get when you want people to be able to share the url, otherwise the post.

Also I recommend looking at sql injection, [SQL injection from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Page1.php**

```
<FORM ACTION='page2.php' METHOD='POST' >
<INPUT TYPE = "text" name="sname" VALUE ="search">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

Now after you navigate to Page2: This code can do the job

**Page2.php**

```
//Check if the paramerter is set and it is not equal to NULL
if( isset($_POST['sname']) && $_POST['sname'] != NULL )
{
     //now load the variable
     $sname = $_POST['sname'];

     //Prevent SQL injection..
     $sname = addslashes($sname);

     $query = "select * from table_name where column_name like '%$sname%'";

     //Execute the query and store in $result
     $result = mysql_query($query);

     // Fetch values from result
     while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array[$result] )
     {
           //Get the values here..
     }
}
```

I assume that you are verymuch aware of SQL Injection.

Comment: You can directly use $_REQUEST['varname'] instead of $_POST or $_GET

Comment: When I click on search, it does not take me to page2.php. I used similar code like you suggested on page1.php.

Comment: I am aware of SQL injection and since this is only for my learning, I am overlooking that for now. Thanks though.

Comment: What action is performed when you click on SEARCH button??

Comment: I got it working. I tried to navigate to page.php when I click search.

Answer (score 0):

Put this values in a form, give textfield a name let say name="fieldname" and give it a method let say post, then access value like this

```
$sname = $_POST['fieldname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='page2.php' method='post'>
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="name">
<INPUT TYPE = "SUBMIT" VALUE ="search">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
```

In page2.php

```
$name=$_POST['name']
```